# How I pass the type dynamically IEnumerable<T> C#

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I want to pass a object type to `IEnumerable<T>` at runtime.

For example, I have to get the read the CSV file and they all return different set of data.

So in case if I want use a single method but extract a different set of entity than how I can do that? In the example shown below, I want to pass different entity instead of `Student`:

```
public List<Patient> GetAcgFileData(string fullFileName) 
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(fullFileName)) 
    {
        var reader = new CsvReader(sr);
        ////CSVReader will now read the whole file into an enumerable
        var records = reader.GetRecords<Student>().ToList();
        return records;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not make your own method generic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your function take in a generic

```
public List<T> GetAcgFileData<T>(string fullFileName) {  
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(fullFileName)) {
        var reader = new CsvReader(sr);
        ////CSVReader will now read the whole file into an enumerable
        var records = reader.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
        return records;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it with a type `GetAcgFileData<Student>("somestring");`

Comment: thanks for answer.  If i am using GetAcgFileData<Student>("somestring"); and want have use the method in a foreach loop, I may want to pass the <Student> and then <Account> how I can do it dynamically?